# frontend_tuner_status doesn't work in Python FEI

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm using the Redhawk IDE 2.0.1 in Centos 6.5.

If I generate a Python based FEI, install, run, allocate, and then try to change the center_frequency via the Properties tab in the IDE I get the error:

Failed to update device property: Center Frequency
Error while executing callable. Caused by org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: Server-side Exception: null  vmcid: 0x41540000  minor code: 99  completed: No
Server-side Exception: null

I've tried to totally different systems and I get the same behavior.

If I do the same thing with the C++ project it works fine. Seems to me the auto generated Python code in 2.0.1 is broken like maybe it's not registering the listener? Any ideas are appreciated as this app will be much easier to implement in Python for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT: Server-side Exception` is a CORBA exception indicating that the FEI device does not implement the `setTunerCenterFrequency` method, despite the FEI device having a DigitalTuner port. The DigitalTuner IDL inherits from the AnalogTuner IDL, which provides the `setTunerCenterFrequency` method. There must be a bug in the implementation of the FEI DigitalTuner port. In `${OSSIEHOME}/lib/python/frontend/input_ports.py`, `InDigitalTunerPort` does not inherit from the `InAnalogTunerPort`, which is where the `setCenterFrequency` method lives. Changing it to the following should fix this issue:

```
class InDigitalTunerPort(FRONTEND__POA.DigitalTuner, InAnalogTunerPort):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=digital_tuner_delegation()):
        InAnalogTunerPort.__init__(self, name, parent)
```

There's a second issue as well. The generated base class instantiates the DigitalTuner port without passing in a reference to itself, the parent. The generated base class of your FEI Device should change from this:

`self.port_DigitalTuner_in = frontend.InDigitalTunerPort("DigitalTuner_in")`

to this:

`self.port_DigitalTuner_in = frontend.InDigitalTunerPort("DigitalTuner_in", self)`